# How can I block outgoing ARP traffic?

Tags: debian, arp

My server keeps sending ARP requests and my provider is not happy with this.
To find out the reason I would like to block all outgoing arp requests (so that my provider doesn't block my server again) and terminate one by one all processes to find out which one is doing this.

How can I block ALL outgoing ARP traffic (maybe using arptables)?

I am running Debian 7.

EDIT:
Output of `ip ro sh`:

```
default via 78.xxx.yyy.41 dev eth0
78.xxx.yyy.40/29 via 78.xxx.yyy.41 dev eth0
78.xxx.yyy.40/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 78.xxx.yyy.46
```

Answer (score 1):

If you block *ALL* outgoing ARP requests, you won't be able to establish any network connections besides perhaps broadcast stuff.

The problem is perhaps that you're sending *unnecessary* ARP requests. I have seen this when the default route is simply declared to be the outgoing network interface and not a gateway. This means that the system has to do an ARP for *all* outgoing IP addresses and that can be a lot if you're serving e.g. a website to the whole world.

The solution in that case was to change the default route to a gateway IP address and not to just an interface name. Now the system only needs to send ARPs for that gateway IP address, which is cached and hence only done at most a couple of times per minute instead of for every unique IP address that connects to your system or your system tries to connect to.

EDIT:

The second line of your `ip ro sh` output is a (the?) problem; you are routing traffic for your /29 subnet via the gateway router, which presumably sends out ICMP redirects to the real host. You should simply delete that route, as the third line will take care of traffic to hosts within your subnet. Please investigate how that route has been added to your system.

Comment: The VPS has already a default route. It is the configuration the provider gives and it always worked!

Comment: Show the output of `ip ro sh`

Comment: default via 78.xxx.yyy.41 dev eth0 \ 
78.xxx.yyy.40/29 via 78.xxx.yyy.41 dev eth0 \ 
78.xxx.yyy.40/29 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 78.xxx.yyy.46

Comment: " \ " indicates a new line. xxx and yyy in ip address means that they are the same numbers.

Comment: It's usual to add extra info to the question; I've done that for you and edited my answer in response to the extra info.

Comment: This was helpful, but still I see a lot of arp requests with tcpdump and I am afraid to keep the connection alive, my vps's ip could be blocked again. I really don't know how to approach the problem!

Comment: So add a selection of the arp requests you see to your question. Also perhaps `ip ro flush cache` is necessary after modifying your routing rules.

Comment: I'll do it as soon as they unlock the server. It has been locked for the fourth time in 3 days.

Comment: Seems like the problem is that my interface responds to all arp request for no reason.

Comment: `head /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/*arp*` should only show zeroes. Besides that I have no idea; anyway, if the network really is a `/29` then there should hardly be any arps. Maybe you're allocated a `/29` but in reality you're in a larger broadcast domain.